# AWS Fargate: unable to pull secrets or registry auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am trying to launch a containerized grpc application on aws fargate.  I've tested the image locally, and have pushed it to ecr.  I've created a task with a role that has permission to reach ecr, yet I am still getting an error pulling the container (error message shown below).  I even tried launching the container in a public subnet with internet gateway/route table association that auto assigns public ips and the security group allows all outbound traffic.

[image: error message]

The full cloudformation template is given below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  TicketingAppTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Essential: true
          Image: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/ticketing-app:latest"
          Name: ticketing-app
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 8080
      Cpu: "1 vCPU"
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      Memory: "2 GB" #this is smallest for 1 vcpu .... could maybe decrease
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RuntimePlatform:
        CpuArchitecture: X86_64
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: [ sts:AssumeRole ]
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [ ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com ]
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
  TicketingEcsService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref TicketingEcsCluster
      LaunchType: FARGATE
  #TODO I think we eventually need to specify load balancers here
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED #TODO remove this when done, just seeing if this let's us grab image from ecr?
          SecurityGroups: [ !GetAtt TicketingServiceSecurityGroup.GroupId ]
          Subnets:
            - !Ref TicketingServicePrivateSubnet01
            - !Ref TicketingServicePrivateSubnet02
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TicketingAppTaskDefinition
  TicketingEcsCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
  TicketingServiceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "A security group used for the ticketing app"
      VpcId: !Ref TicketingServiceVpc
  TicketingServiceVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
  TicketingServicePrivateSubnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}a"
      VpcId: !Ref TicketingServiceVpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/18
  TicketingServicePrivateSubnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}b"
      VpcId: !Ref TicketingServiceVpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.64.0/18
#TODO public subnets and NAT gateway?
  TicketingSecurityGroupHttpIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
  #TODO I would probably use load balancer security group name here once we make one instead of opening up to any ip
      GroupId: !GetAtt TicketingServiceSecurityGroup.GroupId
      CidrIpv6: "::/0"
      FromPort: 8080
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 8080
  TicketingSecurityGroupAllTrafficEgress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !GetAtt TicketingServiceSecurityGroup.GroupId
      IpProtocol: "-1" #-1 indicates all -- like a wildcard
      CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
  TicketingServiceInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    DependsOn: TicketingServiceVpc
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref TicketingServiceVpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref TicketingServiceInternetGateway
  TicketingAppRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref TicketingServiceVpc
  TicketingVPCRouteAllTrafficToInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref TicketingAppRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      GatewayId: !Ref TicketingServiceInternetGateway
```

Would anyone be able to point out a simple way to get this working (even if it uses not best practices, such as public subnet instead of private subnet and nat gateway) -- it is just for a poc.

Thanks

Comment: Some things to check: 1. Do you have DNS Support enabled on the VPC? 2. Are you using a KMS key to encrypt the ECR repository (that the task may not have permission to use)? 3. Do you have a resource policy enabled on the ECR repository that may be blocking access?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
1 - Based on the cf template and the docs, dns support is enabled on this vpc by default.
2 - It does not use a custom kms key for encryption.
3 - It does not look like there is any resource policy (I'm looking at the "private registry permissions").....

any other ideas?

Comment: How do you know the VPC has DNS support enabled? I don't see you creating the VPC in the CloudFormation template. Instead of guessing, just go look at the VPC settings in the AWS console.

Comment: You're deploying into a private subnet. Either configure your service to use public subnets (generally a bad idea), create a NAT (it's on your TODO list), or create VPC endpoints for the services that you need.

Comment: I found the mistake -- I had pushed my image to ecr in a different region.  Changed region and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had pushed my image to ecr in a different region..... changed the region and it worked (face palm).

So check your region if anyone else is in the same spot as me.